# Dice multiplication probability

Tags: probability, dice

I looked into all the probabilities of two dice. Usually it's just 6 x 6; when I listed out all of the combinations, I am confused about why you don't count when the two die have the same number twice.

List of all of the dice combinations:

1,1; 1,2; 1,3; 1,4; 1,5; 1,6;

2,2; 2,3; 2,4; 2,5; 2,6;

3,3; 3,4; 3,5; 3,6;

4,4; 4,5; 4,6;

5,5; 5,6;

6,6

There are a total of 21 combinations; I assumed that you double 21 to get 42.

For example if I call the first dice "dice_1" and the second dice "dice_2" and I take a scenario when 3 and 5 are rolled, dice_1 can yield a 3 and dice_2 would yield a 5, but dice_1 can also yield a 5 which would make dice_2 yield a 3. This would suggest that I double all of the combinations in the above list.

Why don't I double the scenario when two of the same numbers (e.g. 1,1 or 2,2) are rolled?

Comment: Consider cases when dice are of different vs same color

Comment: Look up the difference between combinations and permutations, that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct: They do double—let's re-write the first few lines of your list considering two *different* die. Let's say I have $\text{Die A}$ and $\text{Die B}$. For the first few combinations, we have:

$(1_A, 1_B), (1_A, 2_B), (1_A, 3_B), (1_A, 4_B), (1_A, 5_B), (1_A, 6_B) $

$(1_A, 1_B), (2_A, 1_B), (3_A, 1_B), (4_A, 1_B), (5_A, 1_B), (6_A, 1_B)$

$(2_A, 2_B), (2_A, 3_B), (2_A, 4_B), (2_A, 5_B), (2_A, 6_B)$

$(2_A, 2_B), (3_A, 2_B), (4_A, 2_B), (5_A, 2_B), (6_A, 2_B)$

... Notice the first combination in each line, though. They're duplicates of each other. There's only *one* way for both dice to have the same numbers. Usually, you can switch the numbers. $(2_A, 3_B)$ and $(3_A, 2_B)$ exist as a pair where the numbers are switched. If you try to switch the numbers in $(1_A, 1_B)$, though, you just get... $(1_A, 1_B)$—so there's only a single way for both dice to get the same number.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your presentation, 1,2 can be obtained by throwing a 1 and then 2 or a 2 and then a 1 so two ways but 1,1 can only be obtained by throwing a 1 and then another 1.

Write your table as

1,1; 1,2; 1,3; 1,4; 1,5; 1,6

2,1; 2,2; 2,3;

...

...

and no doubling.

It might be a bit clearer why there are 36 cases.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s color the dice red and green instead. The green die showing a 5 and the red a 3 is clearly different from having a green 3 and red 5, so these are two different events. On the other hand, there’s only one way for both dice to show a 3.